# Solidworks - I need to slope the inner side of the lid

Tags: solidworks

This is the cup lid that I designed, I gave 45deg angle at the bottom which worked well

[image]

Now I want to give the same 45 deg angle at the top but fillet or champer is not working. Now sure what am I doing wrong? I want to give 45 deg angle from the edge to the plate but Champer is not working

[image]

If I select Chamfer, it cut out in the inner side as can be seen below. I want to tapper into center of the lid (plate).

[image]

Comment: Maybe redraw this as a revolved section.

Comment: Generally speaking, one should not use chamfer and fillet etc for functional geometry. There are many maintenance reasons for this. But its very often ignored wisdom, yeah even i do it. Anyway check that your lid actually is one body. Though this probably should be a one sketch revolve.

Comment: just revolve the sketch instead of chamfering

Answer (score 0):

I used Solidworks a little many years ago.

[image]

Try chamfering the other edge.

Comment: If I add Chamfer to the top circle (not bottom as you indicated), it works but it chops of area from the top circle, which I don't want. See the result https://i.imgur.com/9hjXtoq.png

Comment: You didn't explain what happens if you try my suggestion.

Comment: It is the same result that I see in pic 3 in the question itself.

Comment: I found the issue, the two planes were not touching hence the champer was not working correctly, now changing the design to make it work. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Try playing with the chamfer settings, and/or clicking the lower edge.

If that doesn't work try drawing a cross section of the lid and revolving it instead of using the chamfer.

You could even produce just the chamfer manually by using a revolved feature.

The fact is that solidworks sometimes just tweaks out and refuses to produce a feature that it should be able to. However, it's almost always possible to produce the feature in another way. You just kind of learn to deal with the idiosyncrasies after a while.